# Hint request for $x' = x(1 - x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading a graduate textbook on D.E.'s (*Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications* by Chicone) and this is one of the review problems in the first chapter. However D.E.'s. However, it has been 5 years since I took a D.E. class and I do not remember many of the techniques. Could you please provide a hint for solving
$$x' = x(1-x)?$$
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: write $dx/dt = x(1-x)$ then separate the $t$ and $x$ dependent parts to the 2 sides of the equation.

Comment: Hint: separable equation

Comment: Hint: It is also a Bernoulli equation. Compute the DE for $u=1-x^{-1}$.

Comment: @Alex Why give the answer? The question has no effort put into it.

Comment: @Angel I'm sorry I deleted my comment.

Comment: @Moo Oh right you can separate it as $\frac {x'}{x(1-x)} = 1$. Thank you. I did think of doing $\frac {x'}{x} = 1-x$ before but of course that doesn't work so I thought it wasn't separable.

Comment: @am301Thanks, I got it.

Comment: @Angel I got it thank you.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks I see it's separable (easy), but I will read up on this method also.